# Outlook Disconnected, user fixes by clicking work offline twice

Tags: outlook, exchange-2013

We have:
- Exchange 2013 SP1
- Outlook 2013 SP1  (10 users)
- This is a migrated installation, issue was not present before server migration.
- All users are inside the LAN and connected with basic switch.

Issue:  Outlook works for some time, then it says "Disconnected" at the bottom in the status bar.  Outlook stays this way until the user clicks Work Offline (to turn work-offline on), wait 5 seconds, click Work Offline again.  The Outlook connects and works for the rest of the day.

This happens randomly, but about once per day per user and not at the same time.

There is nothing interesting in the event log on workstations or server, no errors.  Viewing Outlook connection status says "Disconnected" and sometimes "Trying...".

We've Tried:
- replacing the switch
- New user profile
- Double checked autodiscover stuff
- Wireshark, shows Outlook just stops sending network packets to server
- IIS pool recycle times (all are set once per day, 3am)

During server migration, a new domain was created and new profiles for each user were setup.